# How to perform users search using twitter ruby gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, twitter-gem

How to perform this [call](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/search) using the [twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter)?

I tried:

```
client.search('sachin')
```

but that returns `Twitter::SearchResults` which contains only tweets.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Twitter::REST::Users#user_search](http://rdoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Users:user_search)

So, using your example, `client.user_search('sachin')`.